# SQL compilation error: Expression type does not match column data type, expecting TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) but got TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9) for column CREATE_DT

Tags: create-table, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

THE QUESTION: WHAT IS THE PROPER DDL TO USE FOR CREATE TABLE...DEFAULT...CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

I have a CREATE or REPLACE statement that uses a DEFAULT for the CREATE_DT column- when someone inserts data into the table, the current server date/time should populate the column

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "EDW_ADMIN"."ETL_SPROC_LOG" (   
   "ETL_SPROC_LOG_ID" NUMBER IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
   "OBJECT_NAME" VARCHAR2(250 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
   "LOG_ENTRY" VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
   "DYNAMIC_SQL" VARCHAR2(10000 CHAR) NULL,
   "DURATION" NUMBER NULL,
   "ROWS_AFFECTED" NUMBER NULL,
   "ERROR_CODE" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR) NULL, 
   "ERROR_DESC" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR) NULL, 
   "CREATE_DT" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
   "CREATE_USER" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_USER()
);
```

When we retrieve data from the column, we would use the following to change the system date/time to our timezone.

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'AMERICA/NEW_YORK';
```

When we execute a sample insert statement like this one we get an error:

```
   INSERT INTO edw_admin.ETL_SPROC_LOG (OBJECT_NAME, LOG_ENTRY) VALUES ('OBJ', 'ENTRY1');

SQL compilation error: Expression type does not match column data type, expecting TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) but got TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9) for column CREATE_DT
```

What is the proper DDL to use for defining the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()?  Do we need to alter the session in the DDL Script prior to the create statement setting the Time Zone to NTZ(9)?  I would think Snowflake has multiple servers in different timezones and therefore the System Time would be dependent on where the server is.

The Snowflake Documentation says

> Returns the current timestamp for the system.
>   https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/current_timestamp.html

It has no arguments to control the Timezone that it returns.

This page in the Snowflake Documentation alludes to the use of CONVERT_TIMEZONE( source_tz, target_tz, source_timestamp_ntz), but again if we are different timezones depending on the server the DEFAULT is executing on I'd think this would fail as well.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html

Comment: If you don't care about the timezone, then use NTZ, which would require that you cast current_timestamp() to timestamp_ntz.  However, I think based on your question, you do want it to be timestamp_ltz, but you want to save the timezone as 'America/New_York'.  The account default is normally based on where your Snowflake account resides, but you can always change it.  The date is always stored in UTC.  Can you be clearer on what timezone you want the current_timestamp() to be in, and then how you want users to see that timezone when querying from different timezones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE ANSWER: USE DATA TYPE TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9) INSTEAD OF TIMESTAMP FOR THE DDL FOR THE COLUMN (see below)

In order to have the date/time come back in the format of whatever you have your session in, it has to be stored in the table with a column defined as a Local Time Zone value, then use ALTER SESSION later on to select it.  This is how the objects in the Information Schema store Timestamps - with data type TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9).

Here's the final code and results

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "EDW_ADMIN"."ETL_SPROC_LOG" (   
   "ETL_SPROC_LOG_ID" NUMBER IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
   "OBJECT_NAME" VARCHAR2(250 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
   "LOG_ENTRY" VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
   "DYNAMIC_SQL" VARCHAR2(10000 CHAR) NULL,
   "DURATION" NUMBER NULL,
   "ROWS_AFFECTED" NUMBER NULL,
   "ERROR_CODE" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR) NULL, 
   "ERROR_DESC" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR) NULL, 
   "CREATE_DT" TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
   "CREATE_USER" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_USER()
);

-- Unit test the new tables identity column and defaults
INSERT INTO edw_admin.ETL_SPROC_LOG (OBJECT_NAME, LOG_ENTRY) VALUES ('OBJ', 'ENTRY1');

ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'America/New_York';
select create_dt from etl_sproc_log;
    2019-11-21 15:04:50.108 -0500

ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles';
select create_dt from etl_sproc_log;
    2019-11-21 12:04:50.108 -0800

ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'GMT';
select create_dt from etl_sproc_log;
    2019-11-21 20:04:50.108 +0000

ALTER SESSION UNSET TIMEZONE;
select create_dt from etl_sproc_log;
    2019-11-21 12:04:50.108 -0800


truncate table edw_admin.etl_sproc_log;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the `TIMESTAMP` data type defaults to `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` unless you set the [Parameter `TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING = TIMESTAMP_LTZ`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#timestamp-type-mapping)

Since `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` produces a `TIMESTAMP_LTZ` value, the data types don't match.

This seems to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TM (
  V NUMBER,
  T TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO TM(V) VALUES(12345);
SELECT * FROM TM;

V       T
12345   2019-11-21 19:03:57.098
```

Comment: It is true that casting CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to timestamp gets the error to go away, however the value stored in the database has no timezone, so you can't really tell when a record was inserted.  It's better to have a TimeZone attached to the data in the table, thus the answer below (and what Snowflake uses in the Inforomatoin Schema - the data type of the column is set to TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9))

Comment: It's OK to use TIMESTAMP_NTZ if you use it to store UTC, but personally I always use TIMESTAMP_LTZ...